# How can I access variables in a closure from inside of a function in that closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

For example:

```
var closure = (function(){
 var closureVariable = "Localized";

 function ReadLocal(){
  //how can I access closureVariable here?
 }
})();
```

Comment: By typing `closureVariable`. Are you actually *calling* `ReadLocal`?

Comment: In JavaScript, inner scopes can access outer scopes; so `closureVariable` is able to be obtained through `ReadLocal`.

Comment: @DaveNewton - No, `ReadLocal()` is never called, this was just an example for scope. Nice catch though ;)

Comment: What you're trying to do is actually a very common [design pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) called the [Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)... it's used everywhere now, especially with AMD modules and when writing plugins. You should also take a peek at the [Revealing Module](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) & [The Mediator](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#mediatorpatternjavascript) Pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `closureVariable`.

For example:

```
var closure = (function(){
 var closureVariable = "Localized";

 function ReadLocal(){
  console.log(closureVariable);
 }
})();
```

`ReadLocal` is an inner scope, and local variables are always visible in inner scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var closure = (function(){
 var closureVariable = "Localized";

 function ReadLocal(){
  //how can I access closureVariable here?
   console.log(closureVariable);
 }
})();
```

closuserVariable is global to readLocal, so you can access it.